# Why won't this definition compile?

Tags: java

I am trying to compile this definition but I keep getting an error. The error says:
1 error found:
File: C:\Users\GreatOne\Desktop\Master Folder\04 (j)\04 - Copy\ObjectDemo2\CreateObjectDemo.java  [line: 32]
Error: origin cannot be resolved to a variable

```
/**
 * This class offers a main method to create and use sample Point and Rectangle objects.
 */
public class CreateObjectDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create a point object and two rectangle objects:
        Point origin_one = new Point(23, 94);
        Rectangle rect_one = new Rectangle(origin_one, 100, 200);
        Rectangle rect_two = new Rectangle(50, 100);

        // Display rect_one's width, height, and area:
        System.out.printf("Width of rect_one: " , rect_one.width);
        System.out.printf("Height of rect_one: " , rect_one.height);
        System.out.printf("Area of rect_one: " , rect_one.area());

        // Set rect_two's position:
        rect_two.origin = origin_one;

        // Display rect_two's position:
        System.out.printf("X Position of rect_two: " , rect_two.origin.x);
        System.out.printf("Y Position of rect_two: " , rect_two.origin.y);

        // Move rect_two and display its new position:
        rect_two.move(40, 72);
        System.out.printf("X Position of rect_two: " , rect_two.origin.x);
        System.out.printf("Y Position of rect_two: " , rect_two.origin.y);
        }

        // A method for moving the rectangle:
        public void move(Point newOrigin) {
           origin = newOrigin;
        }
}

/*
```

Comment: Ummm, cause there is no variable called origin in scope?  Pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: This is my first day working with Java could someone explain how I do this.

Comment: `origin` you never define this, in class scope

Comment: Where do you think `origin`, as seen from the `move` method, is defined?

Comment: @user2510694 If this is your first day I recommend a good introductory tutorial or a book..... Going in half cocked and swinging in this case is more likely to hurt you....

Answer (score 3):

Compilers issue these great things called error messages.  Yes, they can be hard to read at times, but you should develop a skill at reading them.

```
[edwbuck@localhost ~]$ javac CreateObjectDemo.java 
CreateObjectDemo.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
        public void move(Point newOrigin) {
                         ^
  symbol:   class Point
  location: class CreateObjectDemo
CreateObjectDemo.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        Point origin_one = new Point(23, 94);
        ^
  symbol:   class Point
  location: class CreateObjectDemo
CreateObjectDemo.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        Point origin_one = new Point(23, 94);
                               ^
  symbol:   class Point
  location: class CreateObjectDemo
CreateObjectDemo.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        Rectangle rect_one = new Rectangle(origin_one, 100, 200);
        ^
  symbol:   class Rectangle
  location: class CreateObjectDemo
CreateObjectDemo.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        Rectangle rect_one = new Rectangle(origin_one, 100, 200);
                                 ^
  symbol:   class Rectangle
  location: class CreateObjectDemo
CreateObjectDemo.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        Rectangle rect_two = new Rectangle(50, 100);
        ^
  symbol:   class Rectangle
  location: class CreateObjectDemo
CreateObjectDemo.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        Rectangle rect_two = new Rectangle(50, 100);
                                 ^
  symbol:   class Rectangle
  location: class CreateObjectDemo
CreateObjectDemo.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
           origin = newOrigin;
           ^
  symbol:   variable origin
  location: class CreateObjectDemo
8 errors
```

You have 8 errors in the above class.  That's why it won't compile.

Error number 1:

```
CreateObjectDemo.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
        public void move(Point newOrigin) {
                         ^
  symbol:   class Point
  location: class CreateObjectDemo
```

On line 28, you used a class, interface, or enum called `Point` without telling the compiler what `Point` you were using.  In other words, you lack an import statement for the particular `Point` in question, or otherwise haven't defined it within the `CreateObjectDemo.java` file.

Errors 2 and 3:

```
  symbol:   class Point
  location: class CreateObjectDemo
CreateObjectDemo.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        Point origin_one = new Point(23, 94);
        ^
  symbol:   class Point
  location: class CreateObjectDemo
CreateObjectDemo.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        Point origin_one = new Point(23, 94);
                               ^
  symbol:   class Point
  location: class CreateObjectDemo
```

Again, you're using this `Point` thing.  Use an import to let the compiler know where to find it.

Errors 4, 5, 6, and 7

```
  symbol:   class Rectangle
  location: class CreateObjectDemo
CreateObjectDemo.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        Rectangle rect_one = new Rectangle(origin_one, 100, 200);
                                 ^
  symbol:   class Rectangle
  location: class CreateObjectDemo
CreateObjectDemo.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        Rectangle rect_two = new Rectangle(50, 100);
        ^
  symbol:   class Rectangle
  location: class CreateObjectDemo
CreateObjectDemo.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        Rectangle rect_two = new Rectangle(50, 100);
                                 ^
  symbol:   class Rectangle
  location: class CreateObjectDemo
CreateObjectDemo.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
```

Same problem as `Point` but now you are using an undefined class or interface called a `Rectangle`.  Use an import statement to make it clear where the compiler should look for this `Rectangle`.

Error 8:

```
CreateObjectDemo.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
           origin = newOrigin;
           ^
  symbol:   variable origin
  location: class CreateObjectDemo
```

Now you are using a variable called an `origin` but you never told the compiler that you would use `origin` (or what it's type is).  Add a `Point origin;` declaration somewhere before using the variable `origin`.

Comment: +1. I am not sure if I would go into such detail (even as part of a paid service) given the "ask first, disable thinking permanently" nature of the question.

Comment: @TheBlastOne Well, I tend to agree in the sentiment of not overly spoon feeding, but it's hard to really know what's going on on the other side of the Internet.  Sometimes one really does need to be shown how to read compiler output, as it isn't obvious what these cryptic messages mean to everyone (and not everyone has good early guides in learning how to program).  Maybe this is an attempt to "teach them how to fish" instead of "feeding them a fish today"; but, it's kind of hard to "teach fishing" without winding up with a fish surplus.

Comment: Im learning this all on my own so I dont have any help other than here. So it takes me a little while to understand what you guys are trying to explain to me.

Comment: Okay. Note you have a very powerful friend: Google. And existing SO questions. Tutorials are everywhere. Lots of documentation. You are welcome, but it takes more time to write up a usable answer than do some research on the net yourself first. Just mho. The question downvotes acknowledge this. A new user like you should get rep ups, no downs for motivation, so...

Comment: @user2510694 Well, then welcome to working with a great language.  You might want to read the very well written tutorials offered by Oracle. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/  Start with the "getting started" http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html and quickly move on to "learning the java language" http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html  It will give you quite a good introduction to the language, especially if you have little assistance from elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any local variable, or attribute, called `origin` in (respectively) the `move` method or the `CreateObjectDemo` class.

If *that's what you need* declare an attribute called `origin` at the beginning inside your class:

```
private Point origin;
```

Comment: I thought is was a misplaced bracket, but im not sure where.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it. Although the `}` above the `move` method should be to the left, but that's just a small indentation problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your class, you don't have any variable nor parameter named `origin`.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Java `Rectangle` class does not have a way to set the origin with a simple assignment like:

```
origin = newOrigin;
```

And, on top of that, the `move` method has been deprecated since Java 1.1.

Instead, you'll need something along the lines of:

```
rect_two.setLocation (origin_one);
```

See the [Rectangle online Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the problem here is that `origin` is declared as a local variable in `main`, when it needs to be a field in the `CreateObjectDemo` class.

But the real problem is that you have messed up the indentation of your code.  And that made it much harder to spot that `origin` is declared in the wrong scope.

Lesson #1: it pays to take the time to indent your code properly.  You save time in the long run, and you get fewer bruises in your code reviews.

Lesson #2: it pays to read what the compiler message actually says ... and try to understand what it is saying.  In this case, the message is telling you pretty clearly what the problem is.  Unfortunately, it can't tell you exactly what you've done wrong.  (Compilers are no good at working out what you *meant* to write.  They just follow the rules that say what is valid ... and tell you if the program isn't.)

Comment: Do you happen to see where I have messed up my indentation?

Comment: Yup.  The `move` method is indented one level too deep.